# What does りょう mean in かいしゃのりょう?

Tags: translation

I have this line in my book:

> かいしゃの**りょう**はふるいです。

I understand the whole sentence except for りょう.  When I googled it, it says it mean "Ryo". So I googled かいしゃのりょう and I got "Ryo Company".  What does りょう mean?

Comment: This is just another example of why sentences in all hiragana are harder to understand than if they used kanji.

Comment: hahaha right now i only know "人" in kanji 
i hope when i start learning kanji it will be easy like you say :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[寮]{りょう} means "dormitory".

[会社]{かいしゃ}の寮 = company-provided housing facility